# Trouble with url friendly redirection in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running Apache 2.4.33 on Windows 10. Since I updated the new version of Apache these htaccess lines no longer work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\+a-z\ /-]+)\.php$ index.php?lng=$1&page=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\+a-z\ ]+)\.php/([\+a-z\ ]+)/([\+a-z\ ]+) index.php?lng=$1&page=$2&choice=$3&item=$4 [L]
```

The goal is redirecting

mydomain.com/fr/page.php

to

mydomain.com/index.php?lng=fr&page=page

But with the lines above in .htaccess I only get a 404 error. Notice that the Rewrite worked perfectly before. I have modRewrite enabled on my server and it is working with other sites.

Thanks a lot!
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! The problem was that htaccess were not enabled for this account. I had to add these lines of code in my httpd.conf

```
<Directory D:/pages_perso/Websites/mynewsite>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For everyone having similar problem:

1. Test first if .htaccess works. To test it just add any non valid text inside it, say Test
2. Then run your page. IF you see an internal server error, then your htaccess is working. If you don't see anything, then add the above lines in httpd.conf
3. Test if ModRewrite is enable. To do that, add a phpinfo.php page in your server. Add  inside it. Then run. Search for ModRewrite